# Упрощение кода оператора if

Tags: c#

Есть такой код на C#. Можно ли его как-то упростить и привести к однострочному виду, т.е. избавиться от конструкции if..else?

```
 if (String.Equals(path, pattern))
 {
     return true;
 }
 else
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Text");
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: return String.Equals(path, pattern);

Comment: Это то понятно, что так можно, но перед этим нужно вывести сообщение в консоли.

Comment: вы можете заменить if-else на switch-case, но к однострочному виду наврядли приведете.

Comment: @tym32167, любую программу на c# можно записать в одну строку :-)

Comment: ну смысла большого нет, но если это повторяется то return String.Equals("", "z") ? true : sayTextAndReturnFalse("Text"); //функцию думаю понятно как написать.

Comment: Не знаю, насколько вы готовы убирать {} состоящие из одного оператора (в разных командах разный кодстайл), но вообще-то решарпер бы намекнул на Redundant else: экономия одной строки ещё так-сяк, но вот экономия одной табуляции - это уже серьёзнее.

Comment: Решается просто: выдели этот код в отдельный статичный метод и вызывай его в нужных местах вместо того что бы пытатся городить подобные упрощения)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не вижу большого смысла, но может быть так:

```
    public static bool function(string path, string pattern)
    {
        return String.Equals(path, pattern) ? true : sayTextAndReturnFalse("Text");
    }
    public static bool sayTextAndReturnFalse(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: @arantar  `return String.Equals(path, pattern) || sayTextAndReturnFalse("Text");` не советую так делать, вы вашу логику прячете в ньюансы вычисления логического выражения в C#, что может быть проблемой для того, кто потом это будет читать и поддерживать.

Answer (score 7):

```
static T ActionAndReturn<T>(T value, params (T value, Action action)[] actions)
{
    actions.FirstOrDefault(a => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, a.value)).action?.Invoke();
    return value;
}
```

Тогда:

```
return ActionAndReturn(string.Equals(path, pattern), (false, () => Console.Write("Text")));
```

Следующий шаг — делаем это методом расширения и потом пишем:

```
return string.Equals(path, pattern).ActionAndReturn((false, () => Console.Write("Text")));
```

---

Или, как вариант, выкинуть кортежи и `params` вообще:

```
static T ActionAndReturn<T>(this T obj, T value, Action action)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj, value)) action();
    return value;
}
```

и вместо этого просто наращивать методы:

```
return string.Equals(path, pattern)
    .ActionAndReturn(false, () => Console.Write("Text"))
    .ActionAndReturn(true, () => logger.log("log"));
```

Comment: ответ хороший, но код для новичка вроде автора слишком сложный :D

Comment: Как пример - прекрасно. Как код для продакшена, нууу, такая себе замена switch-case :)

Comment: @tym32167 ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Я укоротил свой ответ к более правильному (относительно SRP) варианту :

```
public static class BoolExtension
{
    public static bool WriteMsgIf(this bool value, bool msgShowInCaseof, string consoleMsg)
    {
        if (value == msgShowInCaseof)
            Console.WriteLine(consoleMsg);

        return value;
    }
}
```

и тогда ты делаешь вот так:

```
// выведет сообщение "Test" если они НЕ равны между собой и присвоит в rez значение
var rez = String.Equals(path, pattern).WriteMsgIf(false, "This is the message");

// выведет сообщение "Test" если они равны между собой и присвоит в rez значение
var rez = String.Equals(path, pattern).WriteMsgIf(true, "This is the message");
```

И, снова таки, обрати внимание как легко читается и воспринимается `.WriteMsgIf(true, "This is the message");`

Comment: 1) Вы немного нарушаете SRP, когда метод решает, нужно ли что то выводить + выводит что то на консоль + выполняет проверку на равенство. Слишком много обязанностей для метода.  2) зачем тут сообщение про равенство строк? `var rez2 = StrEqualsWithMsg(path, pattern, "Строки равны!");`, зачем тут вообще тот метод вызвать с параметром false, вместо обычного `String.Equals`

Comment: После того, как вы обращаете внимание на названия методов странно становится видеть в коде имя переменной `rez`, когда есть прекрасное английское слово как `result`. В остальном - апвоут, хотя с нарушением spr согласен. Но боюсь, этого ТС пока не осилит, как не осилит и ActionAndReturn

Comment: на таком примере можно было бы написать `a` или `b` и ровным счетом ничего бы не изменилось бы :)

Comment: @tym32167 2. -- взгляни на сигнатуру метода или почитай коментарий :) 1 - согласен. SRP нарушен. Что бы не нарушался SRP нужно следовать ответу АндрейNOP. Но при этом стоит учитывать еще кому мы даем этот совет, а даем мы ему зеленому новичку. Рано же думать про SRP ему. Окроме того SRP это не закон, а принцип. Его можно и игнорировать иногда :)

Comment: Так погляди на первую функцию, она, если если передать `msgShowInCaseof = false` ничем не отличается от `String.Equals`. А если вызывающий код уже знает значение этого параметра, зачем ему тогда вообще этот метод вызывать в этом случае? Ну и кодекс, как говорил Барбосса, не свод жестких правил, а только рекомендации, просто я отметил что нарушено, если у тебя есть причины так делать, то озвуч их, а то получается принципы нарушаешь просто так.

Comment: Что-то вас парни понесло. Ответы всё мне ясны, кроме первой части ответа **Андрей NOP**.
Вопрос всё таки мой был намного проще, чем вы подумали. Я ведь специально не выделил свой код в метод. _String.Equals_ я привел ради примера, там может быть вообще любой метод возвращающий bool.
Меня интересовало можно ли чисто синтаксически заменить мою конструкцию на похожую с оператором ?: или каким-либо другим.

Comment: @arantar ну тогда читай мой ответ (под подчеркиванием) или ответ АндрейNOP. Его ответ самый лучший и универсальный среди всех ответивших. Мой -- более понятный для твоего уровня :)

Comment: @arantar первая часть кода Андрей NOP более универсальная т.к. дает возможность работать не только с bool но и вообще с любыми данными на входе и любым методом на вызове(а не только вывод текста в консоль). Мой же метод работает исключительно так как ты хотел. То есть заточен только под булл и только на вывод сообщений.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, идеологически правильно не смешивать принт и возвращаемое значение. Так делать не нужно.

Получайте значение и по нему принимайте действия, по месту, в функции которая вызывала результат.

Или можно из этого сделать класс, например WarningString :)

```
   public class WarningString {

      private string __pattern = String.Empty;
      public string Pattern
      {
          set
          {
              if (__pattern != value)
              {
                 __pattern = value;
              }
           }
      }
      public string Value
      {
          get
          {
              return __value;
          }
          set
          {
              if (__value != value)
              {
                 __value = value;
              }
              if ((__value != String.Empty) && (!__value.Equals(__pattern)))
              {
                 TestString = false;
                 Console.WriteLine("not tested");
              }
              else
              {
                 TestString = true;
              }
           }
        }
        public bool Test { get; private set; }
   }

   WarningString ws = new WarningString();
   ws.Pattern = "test 1";
   ws.Value = "test 2";
   if (ws.Test)
       Console.WriteLine("Test ok");
```

Comment: код `((ret) ? void : Console.WriteLine("Тест"));`  имеет целых 2 ошибки. Во первых бул не может быть войдом. И нуллом быть не может. А во вторых врайт лайн возвращает войд а значит не может использоватся в даной конструкции. В даной конструкции и этом контексте нужно вызывать функцию которая возвращает бул.

Comment: Пишу с мобильного, нет возможности проверить, в С работает такая конструкция. Можно поработать с синтаксисом.

Comment: А bool и не может быть void, в этом случае, это условие. Возвращаемый результат пустой - void. Или WriteLine bool возвращает? тогда проще, void надо поменять false например. Задача чтоб возвращаемый тип был один и тот-же.

Comment: Да, в C# с voidне удается однако